# JWT Token and Cookie Chrome Extension With ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, google-chrome-extension, jwt

I've been trying to develop a chrome extensions, but I'm facing a problem that I cloud not work around by my own.

The extension will receive a generical code, and will create a token with jwt, and it will add a cookie with the token created to chrome.

I didn't find a way to use jwt lib using pure javascript in chrome extension to create the token because in pure javascript there is no require/import feature.

I also tested to create a react app. So I can use es6, and I'm allowed to use require/import statement. In this case, I can create the token I need, but I can't inject the cookie on chrome, because chrome extension doesn't allow for exemple cookie injection by 'universal-cookies' lib.

Chrome extension needs a specific API usage to insert the cookie I need, that is `chrome.cookies.set(object, callback);`

So the problem is, with pure javascript I can use chrome API mentioned above, but I can't use jwt to create the token. And with react I can create the token, but I can't use the chrome API.

With react I run `npm run build`, And I set the bundle generated to my extension. But the chrome API throw an error, when I try to bundle the project.

Can some have an idea of how can I work around this problem?

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "React Extension",
  "description": "Trying to create a google chrome extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo192.png",
    "48": "logo192.png",
    "128": "logo192.png"
  },
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "\u003Call_urls>", "cookies", "contextMenus", "unlimitedStorage", "notifications", "storage", "clipboardWrite" ]
}
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { sign } from 'jsonwebtoken';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.createCookie = this.createCookie.bind(this);
  }

  addCookie(token) {
    chrome.cookies.set({
      "url": "http://my.domain.com.br",
      "name": "TOKEN",
      "value": token
    }, function (cookie) {
        console.log("Cookie has been set successfully");
    })
  }

  createCookie() {
    const code = document.getElementById('code').value;

    const token = sign({ claims: null }, "2f41ffb31", {
      subject: code.toString(),
      algorithm: 'HS256'
    });

    this.addCookie(token);
  }

  resetCookie() {
    chrome.cookies.remove({
      "url": "http://my.domain.com.br",
      "name": "TOKEN"
    }, function (cookie) {
      console.log("Cookie has been removed successfully");
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="code" placeholder="code here" />
        <button id="create" onClick={this.createCookie}>Create</button>
        <button id="reset" onClick={this.resetCookie}>Remove</button>
        <span>Token: </span><span id="token"></span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Felipe, what does the error you are getting look like? Have you tried setting the expiration time for the cookie?

Comment: Hi Marcus, when I try to using react, it gives a transpilation error, because it doesn't recognize the chrome api as javascript function (and it's totally true). And when I try to use pure javascript, I'm not able to use import. It's not an error thrown exactly.